# Change rawtext to a variable name?

Tags: php

Is there a way I could possible change raw text to a variable name in a echo. For instance settings a variable `$number` to `number1`, and then when it echoes to use `$number1?`

To clarify, say we have a variable named `$number = "number1";` in it, and when we echo `$number` , it echos a variable named `number1`, how would I change `number1` to a variable? Something like "echo "$"."$number";?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
$number = 2012 ;
$name = 'number' ;
echo $$name ; //2012
echo ${$name};  //2012
echo ${"number"} ;  //2012
echo "${$name}";  //2012
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite easily:

```
$number = 'number1';
$$number = '';
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

or

```
echo $number1;
```

Comment: If you echo it, it would echo an empty string as defined by $$number. $$number takes the value of $number and uses it as it's variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two dollars instead of one. Note that this is really bad practice, and there's probably a better way to achieve your goal here.

```
$number = 42
$usenumber = 'number'
echo $$usenumber //echos 42
```

Comment: @trickyzter: Not the same. Yours is much less clear. Why do I care about `get_defined_vars()`? or `echo $number1;`?

Comment: Both illustrate that the variable exists.